# Relation between meagre sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space and $(Y,\tau_y)$ a topological subspace. If $A \subset Y$ is meagre in $Y$, then $A$ is meagre in $X$.

My attempt of solution:

$A$ meagre in $Y$ $\implies$ $A \subset \bigcup_n \{F_n^y;\,\, F_n^y\,\,\, \text{closed in}\,\,\, Y\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, \text{int}_y(F_n^y)=\emptyset\}.$

So we have that
$A \subset \bigcup_n \{\overline{F_n^y};\,\, F_n^y\,\,\, \text{closed in}\,\,\, Y\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, \text{int}_y(F_n^y)=\emptyset\}$ because $\overline{F_n^y}^y = F_n^y=\overline{F_n^y} \cap Y.$

It is easy to see too that $\text{int}(F_n^y)=\emptyset$ because $\text{int}_y(F_n^y)=\emptyset.$

I need help to prove that $\text{int}(\overline{F_n^y})=\emptyset$

Any help, hint is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U=\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}F_n^y$, and suppose that $U\ne\varnothing$. Let $x\in U$. Then $x\in\operatorname{cl}F_n^y$, and $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so $U\cap F_n^y\ne\varnothing$. But then $U\cap F_n^y$ is a non-empty relatively open subset of $F_n^y$ in $Y$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\operatorname{int}_YF_n^y=\varnothing$.